# simpler way to modify a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I recently solved this problem, but felt there is a simpler way to do it. I'd like to use fewer lines of code than I am now. I'm new to ruby so if the answer is simple I'd love to add it to my toolbag. Thank you in advance.

**goal:** accept a word as an arg, and return the word with it's last vowel removed, if no vowels - return the original word

```
def hipsterfy(word)
    vowels = "aeiou"
    i = word.length - 1
    while i >= 0
        if vowels.include?(word[i])
            return word[0...i] + word[i+1..-1]
        end
        i -= 1
    end
    word
end
```

Comment: Everything in just one sub, without reversals, and no tests: word.sub(/[aeiou](?!.*?[aeiou])/, "")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this regex magic:

```rb
def hipsterfy(word)
  word.gsub(/[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*$)/, "")
end
```

how does it work?

`[aeiou]` looks for a vowel., and `?=[^aeiou]*$` adds the constraint "where there is no vowel match in the following string. So the regex finds the last vowel. Then we just gsub the matched (last vowel) with "".

Comment: Alternatively, use `/[aeiou](?!.*[aeiou])/`. It's probably clearer to use `sub` rather than `gsub`.

Comment: Or `word[/.../] = ''` since it's at most one replacement.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`rindex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#rindex-method) to find the last vowel's index and [`[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) to remove the corresponding character:

```
def hipsterfy(word)
  idx = word.rindex(/[aoiou]/)
  word[idx] = '' if idx
  word
end
```

The `if idx` is needed because `rindex` returns `nil` if no vowel is found. Note that `[]=` modifies `word`.

There's also [`rpartition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#rpartition-method) which splits the string at the given pattern, returning an array containing the part before, the match and the part after. By [`concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#concat-method)-enating the former and latter, you can effectively remove the middle part: (i.e. the vowel)

```
def hipsterfy(word)
  before, _, after = word.rpartition(/[aoiou]/)
  before.concat(after)
end
```

This variant returns a *new* string, leaving `word` unchanged.

Another common approach when dealing with some *last* occurrence is to [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#reverse-method) the string so you can deal with a *first* occurrence instead (which is usually simpler). Here, you can utilize [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#sub-method):

```
def hipsterfy(word)
  word.reverse.sub(/[aeiou]/, '').reverse
end
```

Comment: You are actually forcing me to up vote your answer , great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it.

1. Reverse the characters of the string
2. Use [find_index](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:find_index) to get the *first* vowel location in this reversed string
3. Delete the character at this index
4. Un-reverse the characters and join them back together.

   ```
   reverse_chars = str.chars.reverse
   vowel_idx = reverse_chars.find_index { |char| char =~ /[aeiou]/ }
   reverse_chars.delete_at(vowel_idx) if vowel_idx
   result = reverse_chars.reverse.join
   ```

Comment: You could write `vowel_idx = str.rindex(/[aeiou]/)`. ref [String#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rindex)